# notebook keep using intel hd400 instead of gt635m

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card

hello i have an old model asus n46vj. its powers with i5 and nvidia gt 635m. but lately, the performance in game is very very poor. ive switch via nvidia control panel, clean install and other stuff. until yesterday i fully clean nvidia driver and tried run a game (dota 2). and surprisingly, the game runs exacly the same as the nvidia driver installed. about 50-60 fps. and i made a conclusion that my intel hd 4000 override the gt 635m. is it true or not? if so is there any solutions?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Energy Savings settings in the control panel. Alternatively you could try out the suggestion here: 
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2197694/switch-nvidia-intel-graphic-cards-k55vd-asus-laptop.html